# Insert document with date into collection in Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am working with Robomongo, where I am manually inserting an object.

I want to have a field on my object, which is the current date. Normally I am used to use `Date.now()` in Javascript. However, when I use the insert document form in the Robomongo tool, I get:

```
Unable to parse JSON:
Expecting '(', at (4, 15).
```

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
    serial: '1231323123',
    game: 'World of Warcraft',
    date: Date.now()
}
```

Any idea how to insert this record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this stage it is impossible to do this as stated in the following github issue:

https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/477

> ...there are several differences between Robomongo's JavaScript engine and the v8 engine which is the default in mongo shell 2.4+.

---

[Issue #520](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/520) should fix the problem by updating the built-in shell that comes with Robomongo from SpiderMonkey to v8 (default in MongoDB 2.4+).

Comment: Actually, `Date.now()` works fine. The issue with dates that you referenced is in regards to constructing a new Date() using an ISO string, which you can use `ISODate(...)` for.

Answer (score 6):

Your example works fine if you insert it in the Robomongo 0.8.4 shell prompt directly, for example into a `game` collection:

```
db.game.insert({
    serial: '1231323123',
    game: 'World of Warcraft',
    date: Date.now()
})
```

If you use the context menu (`Insert Document...`), the JSON parser will return the syntax error you are encountering.

The issue here is that the JSON validation is currently done with a library that is not specific to MongoDB. The above is not valid JSON for several reasons (unquoted keys, and the unquoted function value) but *is* valid to insert in the `mongo` shell.

I've created Robomongo [issue #619](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/619) for this. A related JSON validation difference is [issue #448](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/448).

Until the JSON validation error is fixed, I would suggest inserting documents like this via the shell prompt in Robomongo instead.